# Opencart Checkout Page Is Not Moving To The Next Step (opencart v. 2.3.0.2)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart, opencart2.3

I am currently on the opencart checkout page. After inserting my "personal details", it's not moving to the next step of "Delivery Details".

Using **So Topdeal** theme.
http://opencart.opencartworks.com/themes/so_topdeal/intro/

[image]

Comment: Can we see a link on the example? Although, try to look in JS error console for notifications..

Comment: @focus.style this is the link [link](https://cartnaija.com.ng)

Answer (score 0):

Seen your link, checkout page looks perfectly normal, there are no javascript errors. It could be a problem with checkout controller files.

I see, you are using **So Topdeal** theme. Somehow, there is standard checkout page in your website. But, in your theme there should be a **module**, calls **So Onepage Checkout**. You should turn it on and setting it, and everything will work perfectly.

Found that module in theme demo page admin panel (user: **demo**, pass: **demo**). http://opencart.opencartworks.com/themes/so_topdeal/admin/

Admin panel - Extensions - Extensions - Modules - So Onepage Checkout

Comment: I enabled So Onepage Checkout but it's not showing payment processors needed. I want to use paystack and ravepayment, but it's not showing as part of the options (After installing it).